# How to Attach a Pan Gesture Listener on Flutter HERE SDK?

Tags: flutter, here-api, heremaps

I want to trigger else block in this method while the user is navigating the maps with the **pan gesture**.

```
  void setTracking(bool isTracking) {
    if (isTracking) {
      _visualNavigator.cameraMode = CameraTrackingMode.enabled;

    } else {
      _visualNavigator.cameraMode = CameraTrackingMode.disabled;
    }
  }
```

In this way, the user will be able to look at other places on the map while using the navigation. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution;

```
 void _trackingOffOnPanGesture(){
    _hereMapController.gestures.panListener = PanListener((state, origin, translation, velocity) {
      _visualNavigator!.cameraMode = CameraTrackingMode.disabled;
    });
  }
```